# voice recording with silverlight

Tags: silverlight-3.0

How can you record voice in silverlight? Are there any examples showing voice recording in silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight has no microphone / webcam support. You can however record voice in 'Silverlight' via Flash and Javascript.

See the following link...

http://russellgreenspan.blogspot.com/2009/01/microphone-access-in-silverlight-via.html

Answer (score 0):

Go check out the new Silverlight 4 Beta, microphone and web-cam support have been added. Final release is due in early 2010.